# Object is still reachable after leaving the function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, lifecycle

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
  int val;
} node;

node *copy(node *x) {
  node *tmp = &((node){.val = 10});                                             
  return tmp;
}

int main() {
  // node *a = &((node){.val = 9});
  node *a = 0;
  a = copy(a);
  printf("%d\n", a->val);
  return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, every object inside the stack of function will be not accessible after leaving function.
However, it doesn't.

I used GDB to inspect where is the object.

```
(gdb) b 9
(gdb) b 16
(gdb) r
(gdb) p $rsp
$8 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdcc0
(gdb) p $rbp
$9 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdcf0
(gdb) p tmp
$7 = (node *) 0x7fffffffdcdc
(gdb) c
```

```
(gdb) p $rsp
$10 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdd00
(gdb) p $rbp
$11 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdd10
(gdb) p a
$12 = (node *) 0x7fffffffdcdc
```

You can see the variable 'a' point to `0x7fffffffdcdc` which is not between $rsp and $rbp.
Finally the program prints "10" without any error message.
I can't understand why it can works.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior. You can create many kinds of programs that have undefined behavior and they will work as expected. Also pay attention to that the function parameter x is not used.

Comment: Reference: [C11 6.5.2.5p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5): "[...] the compound literal [...] has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block."

Comment: From language perspective, the program has undefined behavior, and observable effect of undefined behavior can be anything, including appearances of program working as expected. From practical purposes, in such a short program the memory which used for holding the now-defunct object has not been reused after the object was destroyed, so you can still look at this memory and find data which you expect to be there. Try calling another unrelated function after `copy`, but before printing the value.

Comment: I use `gcc -O0 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -fsanitize=undefined main.c` to detect undefined behavior, but stdout is empty.

Comment: @SergeyA Like you said, the output value changed after I called a recursive function.

Comment: The static analysis will not catch all instances of undefined behaviour - that would require deeper analysis. As it happens `-O3` performs such deeper analysis and if you set that the issue _is_ caught.  If you want to use the compiler as a _poor man's_ static analysis tool, always use a high optimisation level.   Simpler idioms such as   `node y = {.val = 10}  ;  return &y;` are caught at `-O0`.   At `-O3` it is caught _without_ `sanitize`.  The optimiser is a better static analysis tool than `sanitize` (in this respect at least).

Comment: @Clifford I tried use `cppcheck --enable=all` which I thought was the best tool to to detect undefined behavior, doesn't work either. The method you provided is and simple powerful, thanks for explanation.

Comment: @5f3759df0x Last I tried cppcheck it seemed a pretty weak static analysis tool compared to (expensive) commercial tools.

Comment: @Clifford I'm upset by the fact. It's a recommended tool in my class.

Comment: @5f3759df0x you shouldn't be upset; more sophisticated tools cost money and could not be justified by a school. My advice is to run the compiler at high optimisation as a static analysis check, then run it with no optimisation for debug, and whatever level you wish for release.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for your advice, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object goes out of scope, you can no longer access it by its symbol name.

If you take a pointer (memory address) to the object and return it as you have, the pointer refers to the memory where the object *once existed*.  Nothing specifically happens to that memory content when the object goes out of scope - it just becomes available for other purposes.  So if that memory has not *yet* been reused, it is not remarkable that the memory occupied by the object has not changed.

You are looking at a ghost of an object.  It won't survive long.  for example if you do:

```
  printf("%d\n", a->val);
  printf("%d\n", a->val);
```

You will *most likely* find that by the second `printf()` call it has been modified, because the `printf()` call has used the stack space previously occupied by `tmp` in copy.

Strictly it is *undefined behaviour* and anything could happen.  In practice what I have described is "*typical*" - if something different happens for you, then *shrug*, other things are possible.

Comment: Ya, now I can see the different output.